# Spring+SpringSecurity - AuthenticationEntryPoint Not Called

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am using SpringBoot 2.0.2. I am trying to implement JWT Validation using Spring Security. To handle Invalid Token I am throwing a RunTime Exception. I have added custom authenticationEntryPoint for exception handling.For Valid token it's working perfectly.

**When I am running it as SpringBoot it'w working(and I am getting 401 response). But when I deploy it
   as WAR(I know it's wrong) in Tomcat, it's not getting called.**

In case of WAR it's trying to forward the request to /error page and looking for it's handler method(please see logs at bottom).

Finally I am getting following response:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1576064959206,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Expired or invalid JWT token",
    "path": "/paymentapi-2.0.2.RELEASE/config/credit"
}
```

**What should I change to get 401 ?**

I have following configurations :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

@Autowired
private CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            .csrf().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .cors().disable()
            .headers().frameOptions().disable()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/ping").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/mock/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/customers/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/buyers/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/user/**").hasIpAddress("127.0.0.1")
            .antMatchers("/helper/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/v2/orders/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/transactions/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/paymentCollection/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/paymentRequest").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources", "/configuration/security",
                    "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**", "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui", "/swagger-ui.html",
                    "/swagger-resources/configuration/security").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider))
            .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(paymentEngineAuthenticationEntryPoint);

}
}
```

Following is my custom authentication entry point :

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    public void commence(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
            final AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        //response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Bearer");

        response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        ResponseData responseData = new ResponseData();
        responseData.setMessage(authException.getMessage());
        responseData.setStatusCode(401);
        responseData.setSuccess(false);
        response.getWriter().write(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(responseData));
        response.flushBuffer();
    }

}

 2019-12-11 16:20:16,178 [DEBUG] [http-nio-8082-exec-7] [o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy ] /config/credit at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter' 
        2019-12-11 16:20:16,179 [DEBUG] [http-nio-8082-exec-7] [o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter ] Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@229d8736 
        2019-12-11 16:20:16,179 [DEBUG] [http-nio-8082-exec-7] [s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed 
2019-12-11 16:20:16,179 [DEBUG] [http-nio-8082-exec-7] [o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter ] Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@14816abd 
        2019-12-11 16:20:16,180 [ERROR] [http-nio-8082-exec-7] [o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter ] Forwarding to error page from request [/config/credit] due to exception [Expired or invalid JWT token] com.ril.vms.deadpool.exceptions.InvalidJwtAuthenticationException: Expired or invalid JWT token at com.ril.vms.deadpool.securitycore.JwtTokenProvider.validateToken(JwtTokenProvider.java:74) at com.ril.vms.deadpool.securitycore.JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:31) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        ...
        2019-12-11 17:19:15,628 [DEBUG] [http-nio-8082-exec-7] [o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       ] DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/paymentapi-2.0.2.RELEASE/error]
        2019-12-11 17:19:17,556 [DEBUG] [http-nio-8082-exec-7] [s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping] Looking up handler method for path /error
        2019-12-11 17:19:17,557 [DEBUG] [http-nio-8082-exec-7] [s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping] Did not find handler method for [/error]
        2019-12-11 17:19:17,557 [DEBUG] [http-nio-8082-exec-7] [a.e.w.s.ControllerEndpointHandlerMapping] Looking up handler method for path /error
        2019-12-11 17:19:17,557 [DEBUG] [http-nio-8082-exec-7] [a.e.w.s.ControllerEndpointHandlerMapping] Did not find handler method for [/error]
        2019-12-11 17:19:17,557 [DEBUG] [http-nio-8082-exec-7] [s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] Looking up handler method for path /error
        2019-12-11 17:19:17,558 [DEBUG] [http-nio-8082-exec-7] [s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
        2019-12-11 17:19:17,558 [DEBUG] [http-nio-8082-exec-7] [o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory    ] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'basicErrorController'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolved this issue :

1. In SpringBootServletInitializer I disabled the ErrorPageFilter

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
   public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
   }

   @Override
   protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
       return application.sources(MyApplication.class);
   }

   public PaymentapiApplication() {
       super();
       setRegisterErrorPageFilter(false);
   }}
   ```
2. I wrote a custom filter to catch the specific RunTimeException

   ```
   @Component
   @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
   public class ExceptionHandlerFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

   @Autowired
   private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

   @Override
   protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
   response, FilterChain filterChain)
           throws ServletException, IOException {

       try {
           filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
       } catch (RuntimeException e) {
           // custom error response class used across my project
           if(e instanceof InvalidJwtAuthenticationException) {
               ResponseData responseData = new ResponseData(false, e.getMessage(), 401, 
   null);
               response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
               response.getWriter().write(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(responseData));
           }
       }

   }}
   ```

This way I am getting 401 response.